# How can I send a command and have Errbot respond to me privately?

Tags: python, errbot

I am attempting to use Errbot to create the following workflow:

!calculate  
Errbot then responds to me privately with the answer for number1+number2. I'm not sure how to tell Errbot to respond in a private message, can anyone help assist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do that is to use the config:

```
// in config.py
[...]
DIVERT_TO_PRIVATE = ['calculate',]
[...]
```